# googleapi: Error 403: Quota 'BACKEND_SERVICES' exceeded. Limit: 9.0, quotaExceeded

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm encountering the following error for my ingress controller.

```
Warning     GCE googleapi: Error 403: Quota 'BACKEND_SERVICES' exceeded. Limit: 9.0, quotaExceeded
```

My limit is set as 9, and this has previously worked so I'm not sure why this error is being encountered now.

I did delete the cluster and then created a new one, what do these backend services refer to? How could I remove any old ones that have not been deleted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to delete the previously created Load balancers, and the related "backends" in the Google Cloud console.

The quota was shortly updated after that.

Comment: how did you do this ?

Comment: @grabbag on your project console page, select the menu, scroll down to Network services (in the subsection Networking), then select Load balancing. Now you can remove the offending load balancer.

Comment: https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/loadbalancing/backends/list - backends list link

Answer (score 12):

You could also ask for a small up on the [backend # quota page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas).

If it's small enough it will get auto accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Just a heads up — I ran into this quickly trialing a Multi Region GCE Ingress deployed using Kubemci.  Since you are essentially duplicating your backend across many regions the maximum number of regions you could use on a GCP Trial Account would be 5.

GCP will force you to upgrade to a full account (and enter billing if you haven't yet).  Not a big deal but in my instance I had do this in order to test a service being served from more than 5 regions at once — where the error was not immediately evident in the logs.

When trouble shooting the rest of the Multi-Region Ingress process this one was tricky to track down — so hopefully this saves a bit of time for someone trying to deploy many clusters on a trial account (like I was!).