# BACKEND_SERVICES exceeded in Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I'm having the problem described here:

[googleapi: Error 403: Quota 'BACKEND_SERVICES' exceeded. Limit: 9.0, quotaExceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46450415/googleapi-error-403-quota-backend-services-exceeded-limit-9-0-quotaexceed)

> Warning
> GCE googleapi: Error 403: Quota 'BACKEND_SERVICES' exceeded.
> Limit: 9.0, quotaExceeded

We are pretty new to GKE, we created some services using this template-like (helm's default)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "monolito"
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: "monolito"
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: "monolito"
```

And we added some other services that we have currently deployed in a VM / App Engine.

We don't understand why this quota exists. Are we doing something wrong? Isn't it normal to have more than 10 services when doing Kubernetes / microservices approach?
Do we need the load balancers that are passing the quota?

Comment: Have you checked the question [googleapi: Error 403: Quota 'BACKEND_SERVICES' exceeded. Limit: 9.0, quotaExceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46450415/googleapi-error-403-quota-backend-services-exceeded-limit-9-0-quotaexceed)?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza yes, it is linked in my question. I'm asking if we are doing something wrong or this is just Google Cloud having extremely low quotas. Each time I add an endpoint to our single Ingress pointing to a service, it seems to create a Backend Service. We aim to 4 services in 6 namespaces and we quickly got to the 9 BE services quota

Comment: So, there's no issue, it's expected behavior.